# User control keeps stretching once dropped on form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

This may be a winforms newb mistake, but I've created a user control that has one component on it - a Telerik dropdownlist control. When I initially drop it on a form it looks correct. However, as soon as I run the form the control stretches off the form.

The dropdownlist on the user control has its anchor property set to top/left/right/bottom.

Before:

[image: Here's what it looks like immediately after dropping it on the form]

After:

[image: Here's what it looks like after running]

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: a bit more info: If I close the designer and open it back up, it immediately changes sizes. The code itself doesn't appear to cause the problem. In fact, I commented out all of the code (besides the InitializeComponent() call) and I still see the problem. The control itself still works - when I run the form it is populated with the data I'm expecting. It's just stretched.

I can "work around" the issue by setting the width of the dropdownlist about 35 pixels less than the size I actually want it to be, so when it resizes itself it's actually the correct width, but I really shouldn't have to.

Comment: The user control in the form? Did you try to "identify" (for example assigning different background colors, dropdown in blue, usercontrol in red...) where each control is?

Comment: Possibly you can post a little bit of Code to show us how the controls are implemented

Comment: From the designer, if you resize the form containing your user control do you see this issue?  Check your anchor settings on both the user control and the component on the user control.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably on the right track.  It looks as though it is anchoring to something that is way off the page.  I would try removing the anchor right for starters to see what effect this has.  If that doesn't work, perhaps try different combinations of the anchoring to see what effect it has on the control.

Make sure there are no docking settings enabled, as it would undo any anchoring you have on the control.

Check to see what the dropdownlist control is contained in.  You said it was in a usercontrol, but is it within a grid in the UC or anything else like that?  Also, ensure that the user control is sized properly (not outside the bounds of the page) -- would cause anchoring problem.  Use a background color to test this.

Next, I would check the Maximum/Minimum size of the control (perhaps consider setting one?).

If all else fails, delete the dropdownlist and create a new one and see if you have the same problem.  Sometimes the designer side of code gets glitchy and causes problems or you just accidentally change something you didn't mean to.

Finally, last resort, just use a normal drowndownlist ;)